# Error importing delta package into Synapse notebook

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I need to import delta-spark package into Azure Synapse notebook but I receive error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.errors'".

The package is installed (along with pyspark). Imports from pyspark (such as pyspark.sql.functions) work but import of DeltaTable fails on pyspark.errors.
Same import works in different environment (Databricks notebook) with same package versions.
I tried to use findspark but it solved nothing (probably because I don't have issue importing pyspark but some package under pyspark).

code:

```
%pip install delta-spark
```

output (selected):

```
Requirement already satisfied: delta-spark in /nfs4/pyenv-fee9cba1-d59a-44ab-8b9e-957614b27f23/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.0.0)  
Requirement already satisfied: pyspark<3.6.0,>=3.5.0 in /nfs4/pyenv-fee9cba1-d59a-44ab-8b9e-957614b27f23/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from delta-spark) (3.5.0)
```

code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
```

output (selected):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 10
      8 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
      9 from pyspark.sql import Window
---> 10 from delta.tables import DeltaTable

...

File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/delta/exceptions.py:20
     17 from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Optional
     19 from pyspark import SparkContext
---> 20 from pyspark.errors.exceptions import captured
     21 from pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured import CapturedException
     22 from pyspark.sql.utils import (
     23     AnalysisException,
     24     IllegalArgumentException,
     25     ParseException
     26 )

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.errors'
```

This is the environment setting of the Spark pool:

```
SPARK_HOME -> /opt/spark
PYTHONPATH -> /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip<CPS>/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip<CPS>/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip<CPS>/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
```

Comment: Did you tried `from delta.tables import DeltaTable` before installing `delta-spark` package?x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
```

This command will work in synapse notebook without installing the `delta-spark` package.

I got same error when I tried to use `from delta.tables import DeltaTable` command after `%pip install delta-spark`.

But before installing it, the above is working fine. Installing `delta-spark` upon the `delta` package in synapse notebook might be the reason for the above error.

To use `from delta.tables import DeltaTable`, don't install the `delta-spark`. You can directly use it like below.

[image]

You can see, it is working fine without installing any package.